# Script to check files at a server for a certain time

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I'd created below script to check files remaining at a particular path in server.

I've below question please help me out.

- How to change file.CreationTime to 12 hours format.
- How to export the entire contents to file or email.

Kindly help me in fine tuning the below script

```
$fullPath = "\\server\D$\fn_1"
$numdays = 0
$numhours = 0
$nummins = 1

function ShowOldFiles($path, $days, $hours, $mins)
{
    $files = @(get-childitem $path -include *.* -recurse | where {($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-$days).AddHours(-$hours).AddMinutes(-$mins)) -and ($_.psIsContainer -eq $false)})
    if ($files -ne $NULL)
    {
        for ($idx = 0; $idx -lt $files.Length; $idx++)
        {
            $file = $files[$idx]
            write-host ("File Name: " + $file.Name, ", Pending Since : " + $file.CreationTime) -Fore Red


        }
    }
}

ShowOldFiles $fullPath $numdays $numhours $nummins
```

Answer (score 0):

To dump to a file, replace your whole `for` loop with this:

```
$files | select-object Name,@{name="Pending Since";Expression={$_.CreationTime}}|export-csv -notypeinfo -path c:\output.csv;
```

This will produce a CSV file with all of your files listed, along with their creation time. Save the formatting for your final delivery/presentation to the user (in this case, you could format the columns in Excel & then save as XLSX).

To send via email, you'll probably want to convert it to HTML.

```
$filesForEmail = $files | select-object Name,@{name="Pending Since";Expression={$_.CreationTime}} | convertto-HTML;
send-mailmessage -to RECIPIENT -from FROM -subject "Your file listing" -body $filesForEmail -BodyAsHTML -smtpserver smtp.yourcompany.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You can format the CreationTime value by running it through get-date and using the -format command and the standard DateTime formatting options (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo(VS.85).aspx). Try this line:

```
write-host ("File Name: " + $file.Name, ", Pending Since : " + $(get-date $file.CreationTime -format "dddd, MMMM d, yyy h:mm tt")) -Fore Red
```

The main bit here is replacing `$file.CreationTime` with `$(get-date $file.CreationTime -format "dddd, MMMM d, yyy h:mm tt")`. That is a fairly standard date/time format with 12 hour formatting. You could get more detailed if you wanted and define the format earlier and only put out relevant info (such as, if days = 0 exclude that from the date format).